# Cannot test on more than one iPhone

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

I have a iPhone 4 and a iPhone 3GS.  Have managed to download and install the necessary certificates on my iPhone 3GS and set up the phone as a test machine with a sample program.  But I cannot do the same with my iPhone 4.  I wonder if Apple has placed a limitation that only one iPhone can be registered as test machine.

Hope that some knowledgable person can confirm to me that there is indeed a one test phone limitation.  Or somebody can show me how to use both phone models (4 & 3GS) (not at the same time) as test machines.

Comment: With the $99 developer package, you can install your app on up to 100 test devices. What specific problem are you encountering? (Update your question with any error messages, etc.)

Comment: When I click "Build and Run" in Xcode a msg comes up :

Comment: When I click "Build and Run" in Xcode a msg comes up : "Can't run ... on the iPhone ... Click (Install and Run) to install the provisioning profile ... and continue running."  But when I click (Install and Run) it says "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."  But this only happens on my iPhone 4, on my iPhone 3GS everything is ok.

Comment: The whole process of "provisioning" test devices is trickier than expected. Your comment although not exactly an answer does help.  As it confirms that more than one test phones are allowed.  Otherwise the seemingly endless frustration in trying to set up the test devices can be even more unbearable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you registered the UDID of a device in the provisioning portal and selected it when you created the mobileprovision, then you should be able to install that provision on the device using Xcode's Organizer.  If it doesn't let you, go back to the portal and check the UDIDs you used.

If you can install the profile on your iPhone 4, but the app won't run, check which profile you used for the exact current type of Build of the current Target which you are trying to run (as every Build can use a different profile.  And Target settings over-ride Project settings).

Comment: In the process of finding the UDID I stumbled upon a "Automatic Device Provisioning" check box and its "Refresh" button.  I clicked on the button and everything seems to be ok now.  I may have used a similar process when setting up the first phone.  But then I have changed the Device name of the iPhone 4 in iTune a day before trying to set it as test device also.  The name change may be the cause for the previous "Auto Provisioning" to fail.  So I haven't use the UDID value at all.  But it is very likely that we will need it in the long run...